# Angular directive takes old value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
           app.directive('countdown', [
    'Util',
    '$interval',
    '$rootScope',
    function (Util, $interval, $rootScope) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: { 
                date: '@',
                type: '@'
            },
            link: function (scope, element) {
                var future, stopTime;
                var t = scope.date.split(/[- :]/);
                future = new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);
                stopTime = $interval(function () {
                    var diff, now, now_utc, text, res;
                    now = new Date(); 
                    now_utc = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(),  now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
                    diff = Math.floor((future.getTime() - now_utc.getTime()) / 1000);
                    text = Util.dhms(diff);
                    res = element.text(text);
                    if(text === '00:00:00'){
                        $interval.cancel(stopTime);
                        element.addClass('blink');
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                                $rootScope.updateStatus('ended');
                            });
                        }, 2000);
                    }
                    return res;
                }, 1000);
                element.on('$destroy', function() {
                    $interval.cancel(stopTime);
                });
            }
        };
    }
]).factory('Util', [function () {
    return {
        dhms: function (t) {
            var days, hours, minutes, seconds;
            days = Math.floor(t / 86400);
            t -= days * 86400;
            hours = Math.floor(t / 3600) % 24;
            t -= hours * 3600;
            minutes = Math.floor(t / 60) % 60;
            t -= minutes * 60;
            seconds = t % 60;
            if(days > 0 ){
                hours = hours+(days*24);
            }
            hours = (hours < 10) ? "0"+hours : hours;
            minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0"+minutes : minutes;
            seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0"+seconds: seconds;

            return hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
        }
    };
}]);
```

HTML

```
<span class="timer" countdown='' type='active' date='{{end}}'><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-fw"></i></span>
```

I've issue with directive when page changes it takes a previous value from date, so I need to go back and again open that page so the value updates.

The value in HTML it is correct but `console.log(scope.date)` gives old value.

Can somebody assist?

Comment: Might be worth replacing `date: '@'` with `date: '='`

Comment: = it takes the variable @ takes the value I've tried didnt helped, but also = better work when you declare scope in controller.

Comment: the part about switching pages is unclear and  a bit confusing

Comment: @charlietfl steps
I'm on home page -> click on sub page (where dirictive fires) after return to home page and  -> click another sub page (new directive should fire) but I see value from first subpage.

Comment: we can't see where `end` comes from. If you need this to monitor time you would need a service to store it

Comment: End comes from controller $http.post

Comment: Please provide sample of how you're using the directive in HTML.  It is possible you are using the same directive instance across your 'pages' hence the same data.